# How does the underlying topological space of manifold depend on the properties of the atlas?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, second-countable

Let $X$ be a set.

In Serge Lang's "*Differential and Riemannian manifolds*" the following definition of smooth $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-atlas on $X$ is given.

> Let $I$ be some index set. An atlas of class $C^{\infty}$ on $X$ is a collection of pairs $\{(U_{i},\phi_{i})\}_{i \in I}$, satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. Each $U_{i}$ is a subset of $X$, and the $U_{i}$ cover $X$.
> 2. Each $\phi_{i}$ is a bijection of $U_{i}$ onto an open subset $\phi_{i}U_{i} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. And for each $i,j \in I$, the set $\phi_{i}(U_{i} \cap U_{j})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
> 3. For all $i,j \in I$, the map
>      \begin{equation}
>    \phi_{j}\phi_{i}^{-1}: \phi_{i}(U_{i} \cap U_{j}) \rightarrow \phi_{j}(U_{i} \cap U_{j})
>    \end{equation}
>      is a diffeomorphism.

It then follows that the collection $\{ \phi_{i}^{-1}(V) \mid i \in I, \, V \text{ open in } \phi_{i}U_{i} \}$ is a base for a topology on $X$. The maps $\phi_{i}$ are continuous and open with respect to this topology, and hence homeomorphisms.

Now I have two questions.

> Is $X$ automatically Hausdorff? If not, what condition needs to be put on the atlas to ensure that $X$ is Hausdorff?

It seems to me that because $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Hausdorff it follows that $X$ is as well, but I'm not quite seeing how to prove this.

> Under what conditions is $X$ second-countable.

It seems to me that it is sufficient that the index set $I$ is countable is a sufficient condition. By taking the sets $V$ in the definition above to be members of a countable base for the topology of $\phi_{i} U_{i} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the definition above one obtains a countable base for $X$, (it is a countable union of countable sets).

> Can this condition be weakened in a sensible way, or can it be shown that this condition is "necessary"? (In the sense that if $X$ is second-countable, one can always find a countable subset $I' \subset I$ such that $\{(U_{i}, \phi_{i}) \}_{i \in I'}$ is an atlas that gives the same manifold structure to $X$.)

Comment: The line with two origines is an example of non-Hausdorff, second countable, locally euclidean space.

Comment: For your last question: choose a countable dense set $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \subset X$, then define $I'$ by choosing some $U_i \ni x_i$ for each $x_i$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861646/topology-given-by-atlas-is-paracompact) question may be useful for you.